# PIMCORE: getting 500 Error, Grid column configuration with objectbricks

Tags: php, pimcore

Getting Below Error in PIMCORE demo Site

Senario: product grid adding new objectBricks Column and try to sort by id[image]

```
Status: 500 | Internal Server Error
URL: /admin/object/grid-proxy/classId/12/folderId/33?xaction=read&_dc=1491992052100
Params:
-> language: en_GB
-> class: Product



Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception' with message 'Mysqli prepare error: Column 'o_id' in order clause is ambiguous' in /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php:77
Stack trace:
#0 /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(115): Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare('SELECT COUNT(*)...')
#1 /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php(388): Zend_Db_Statement->__construct(Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli), 'SELECT COUNT(*)...')
#2 /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*)...')
#3 /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(828): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(Object(Zend_Db_Select), Array)
#4 [internal function]: Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne in /home/pimcore_ecommercedemo/www/vendor/zendframework/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php on line 77
```

Related issue on github:
https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/1439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please ckeck solution for below link.
Solution : `https://github.com/pimcore/pimcore/issues/1439`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a JOIN problem. When two tables have similar columns, (i.e. o_id), MySQL is not sure which column you mean. You have to specify tablename.o_id in order to get rid of this ambiguity error message.

Comment: inside actual query getting order by `ORDER BY o_id DESC` expected  `ORDER BY primary_table_name.o_id DESC` bcs o_id used in join clue